# Is there a way to wait for get connected? A callback? A listener?

Tags: android, android-intent, callback, settings, wait

I'm doing an app that has a Login Activity, when I get into this activity I ask the user to enable WIFI or MOBILE DATA if there is no conection to my server. I give 3 options, WIFI, MOBILE DATA and CANCEL in a Dialog.

```
public void checkConnectionDialog(Context context){

        if( dialogConnection != null && dialogConnection.isShowing() ) return;

        dialogConnection = new Dialog(context);
        dialogConnection.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        dialogConnection.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
        dialogConnection.setCancelable(false);

        dialogConnection.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_connection);

        Button bt_data = (Button) dialogConnection.findViewById(R.id.bt_data);
        Button bt_wifi = (Button) dialogConnection.findViewById(R.id.bt_wifi);
        Button bt_cancel = (Button) dialogConnection.findViewById(R.id.bt_cancel);


        bt_data.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_DATA_ROAMING_SETTINGS));
                dialogConnection.dismiss();
            }
        });

        bt_wifi.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_WIFI_SETTINGS));
                dialogConnection.dismiss();
            }
        });

        bt_cancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dialogConnection.dismiss();
                setResult(RESULT_CANCELED, null);
                finish();
            }
        });

        dialogConnection.show();
    }
```

With Intents, I send users to WIFI or MOBILE DATA settings. If user enable the wifi or the data and come back (pressing back button), the system takes a few seconds to get connected to internet.

If the user clicks back just after enabling internet, when he returns to the application it still has no connection.

What I want to know is how can I make the application wait to have connection to continue.

**APP (NOT CONNECTED) --> Intent (WIFI OR DATA ENABLED) --> APP (WAITING UNTIL CONNECT TO SHOW A VIEW)**

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Create a BroadcastReceiver which will fire an Event when you are connected to Internet :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can register a `BroadcastReceiver` which listens for network changes in your activity. Something like this:

```
BroadcastReceiver connectionReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent != null && intent.getAction().equals(ConnectivityManager
                .CONNECTIVITY_ACTION)) {

            boolean isConnected = ConnectivityManagerCompat.getNetworkInfoFromBroadcast
                    ((ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE),
                            intent).isConnected();

            if (isConnected) {
                onConnectionEstablished();
            } else {
                onConnectionAbsent();
            }
        }
    }
};
```

The connection established and absent are just void methods which does something that you want, like:

```
public void onConnectionEstablished() {
       // do something
}

public void onConnectionAbsent() {
       // do something
}
```

Register and unregister the receivers `onPause` and `onResume`

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
    filter.addAction(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION);
    registerReceiver(connectionReceiver, filter);
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    try {
        unregisterReceiver(connectionReceiver);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can receive connection changes with the following manifest intents. Put them inside the reciver as intent-filter. Please note that this is just from scratch and I can´t test it for now!

```
<action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE"/>
        <action android:name="android.net.wifi.STATE_CHANGE"/>
```

You receive this every time the connection has changed, but You have to do some work in Your BroadcastReceiver to check if it is connected or not:

For example, You could listen in onReceive():

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, final Intent intent) {
    ConnectivityManager manager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo info = manager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);

    if (info.isConnected()) {
        //then You know it is connected and can do some stuff
    }else{

      //not connected.....
    }
}
```

For example, now You can start a service to do some things to inform Your User about it is connected or not.